# How do I change the email address where I get email from StackExchange?

Tags: support

How do I change the email address where I get email from StackExchange?

The email server I previously used wants to shut down my account.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials and also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1847/225557

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403233/locked-out-trying-to-change-email